# apn_on_rails breaking view helpers on rails 2.3.8?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, apple-push-notifications, actionview

I am developing a rails application which should send push notifications to iOS devices. I am using apn_on_rails gem. Everything works fine in the rails console. However when I run the server, I get undefined method errors for all the basic view methods such as `content_for` or `form_tag` etc:

When I take `require 'apn_on_rails'` from my `development.rb` out, the views work again, but of course without push notifications.

Here is an example trace:

```
Processing DashboardController#index (for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-02-27 13:55:59) [GET]
User Load (0.2ms)   SELECT * FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."id" = 1) 
CACHE (0.0ms)   SELECT * FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."id" = 1) 
Rendering template within layouts/dashboard
Rendering dashboard/index

ActionView::TemplateError (undefined method `content_for' for #<ActionView::Base:0x103343970>) on line #1 of app/views/dashboard/index.html.erb:
1: <% content_for :header do %>
2:  <%= render :partial => "header", :locals => {:title => "Dashboard"} %>
3: <% end %>


app/views/dashboard/index.html.erb:1
app/controllers/dashboard_controller.rb:6:in `index'

Rendered rescues/_trace (28.5ms)


Processing ApplicationController#index (for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-02-27 13:55:59) [GET]

ActionView::TemplateError (undefined method `debug' for #<ActionView::Base:0x103343970>) in /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb:



Rendered rescues/_trace (24.0ms)
/!\ FAILSAFE /!\  Sun Feb 27 13:55:59 +0100 2011
 Status: 500 Internal Server Error

ActionView::TemplateError (undefined method `debug' for #<ActionView::Base:0x1031eaad8>) in /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb:




In /library/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb
```

Thanks for any help...

Comment: I wonder what that development.rb file looks like..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not evident whether you call `config.gem 'apn_on_rails'` - it sounds more like you are `require`:ing the library, which probably is something you should not do at this point: the point of environment setup.

Have the config.gem things in your environment setup (i.e. development.rb), but make eventual `require`s happen later (->in the controller / model / helper in question).

Comment: Thanks conny. Adding `config.gem` and moving the requires to the controller solved the problem indeed.